# VScode is outputting None and weird things after not updating the same file with a before valid output

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, path, output

```
print("test")

def walk(direction, map):
    if direction == 'up' or 'down' or 'left' or 'right':
        if direction == 'up':
            pass
        if direction == 'down':
            pass
        if direction == 'left':
            pass
        if direction == 'right':
            pass
    else:
        print("Please give a viable direction")

win = False
map = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
]

x_coor = 0
y_coor = 0
position = map[y_coor][x_coor]
print(position)

while not win:
    print(position)
    direction = input("In which direction do you want to go: ")
    position = walk(direction, map)

    if position == int(2):
        win = True
    if win == True:
        print("You have won")
```

For the last few days I had a problem with my vscode, which occurs only in some type of files. It is the output which is turning to None even when I do not change the code. e.g here:

Please don't judge the program in itself and how unclean it is this is my first draft of doing something like that. if the code is working is the only thing I care about right now.

So if I run that code it gives me the output I expect, but when running it a second time gives me None and a strange bin location on my Mac. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9MMv.png)

Is this because of my code, because I had similar problems in other projects as well that the code showing in the terminal is suddenly changing to weird locations and outputs.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: For <your deity if any here>'s sake, don't post images of console output: you're using a bazooka to kill an ant. Select the text, paste it here using appropriate formatting.

Comment: sorry, I don't know what to do and thought that it would be better to show the full path where it is running because I do not understand why it is running in /bin

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems broken.

Here is some tests I made.

```
In [8]: print("test")
   ...:
   ...: def walk(direction, map):
   ...:     if direction == 'up' or 'down' or 'left' or 'right':
   ...:         if direction == 'up':
   ...:             pass
   ...:         if direction == 'down':
   ...:             pass
   ...:         if direction == 'left':
   ...:             pass
   ...:         if direction == 'right':
   ...:             pass
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print("Please give a viable direction")
   ...:
   ...: win = False
   ...: map = [
   ...:     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   ...:     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   ...:     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   ...:     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   ...:     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
   ...: ]
   ...:
   ...: x_coor = 0
   ...: y_coor = 0
   ...: position = map[y_coor][x_coor]
   ...: print(position)
   ...:
   ...: while not win:
   ...:     print(position)
   ...:     direction = input("In which direction do you want to go: ")
   ...:     position = walk(direction, map)
   ...:
   ...:     if position == int(2):
   ...:         win = True
   ...:     if win == True:
   ...:         print("You have won")
   ...:
test
1
1
In which direction do you want to go: up
None
In which direction do you want to go: down
None
In which direction do you want to go: left
None
In which direction do you want to go: right
None
In which direction do you want to go: foo
None
In which direction do you want to go: bar
None
In which direction do you want to go: baz
None
In which direction do you want to go: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 32
     30 while not win:
     31     print(position)
---> 32     direction = input("In which direction do you want to go: ")
     33     position = walk(direction, map)
     35     if position == int(2):

KeyboardInterrupt:

In [9]: map
Out[9]:
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]]

In [10]: walk("up", map)

In [11]: map
Out[11]:
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]]

In [12]: walk("down", map)

In [13]: map
Out[13]:
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]]

In [14]: x_coor
Out[14]: 0

In [15]: y_coor
Out[15]: 0
```

Your `walk(direction, map)` does nothing and returns nothing and `x_coor` and `y_coor` will always be 0.

You may have used the "up arrow" keyboard key instead of typing `up`: in most shells/consoles, up arrow will type the previous user input in the console (which here seems to be the command to launch your python script).

1. Fix your walk function, and correctly use and set a position variable to keep track of the position
2. Bonus activity:
   a. handle out of map situations,
   b. keep track of the used path a colored map of the path console
   c. intercept keyboard arrow key press instead of having to type "up"/"down" etc.

Protip: extensively read the python documentation, like:

- https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/
- https://docs.python.org/3.10/

Comment: okey thanks a lot. But still I would like to understand how it is possible that if I run my code the output is:
test
1
1
and if I run the program again it just returns None, how is that possible when I start the whole program again without changes that the output suddenly changes?